# Unable to render component when using Map as state type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am fairly new to React. I was trying to create below component

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Map<string, MyData>>(new Map<string, MyData>())

  useEffect(() => {
    const parsedData: Map<string, MyData>> =
      JSON.parse(mockedData)
      setData(parsedData)
  }, [])

  return <>{data.size > 0 ? getDataComponents() : <></>}</>
}
```

As part of this, I am using `mockedData` to replicate the data I would receive from an API. This compiles correctly.

However at runtime, when the render cycle is triggered post effect, `data.size` is shown as `undefined` as data type is object instead of Map, due to which `getDataComponents()` is never triggered. I can also see the values on the object but not entirely certain what is causing it to be not identified as Map.

Comment: why don't you convert array to Map in the component then you would have more control over the data alongside having globally recognised data type in API response

Comment: You assign an object to `parsedData`, then your confused when it's and object and not a map... ?

Comment: FYI: `JSON.parse` returns `any`, that's why you're not getting a TS error here.

Comment: @super thanks. I see what I was doing wrong! I was being misled by the parsedData type.